# Is There Any Way to Pass Both ID and Slug from getStaticPaths to getStaticProps [nextjs]

Tags: next.js

I want to set my URL's as slugs in my next.js app, but also need to pass the itemID to getStaticProps in order to get the data I need from my API.

How can I pass both ID and slug from getStaticPaths to getStaticProps rather than one or the other?

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = items.map(item => (
    { params: { id: item.itemID }}
  ))

  return {paths, fallback: false}
}
```

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
const paths = items.map(item => ({ 
      params: { 
        id: item.itemID,
        title: item.description
      }
    }))
```

Comment: Hi, did you manged to get this working? I am also looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you using this to fetch post from Contentful? If so then there is another way to fetch post from Slug without passing the ID.  You can filter the collection with slug using where argument like `query{collection(where: {slug: 'slug'}){...}`

Comment: How did you finally solve this problem?

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can find the answer to your question in this [blog example from Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly). They call `getStaticPaths()` first to get a list of all paths, and then pass that information over to `getStaticProps()` to get data for each of the paths. Since the data is generated at build time, I believe Nextjs gets all your pages built and ready to serve in one go.